# How to create a count PL SQL Function that accepts multiple parameters?

Tags: sql, oracle

My professor has assigned me to create a PL SQL function for a university style database. The function should return a count of the number of courses a professor is teaching in a particular year. However my current code is just returning a count of every record in the table and I'm not sure why. FacSSN is simply a faculty identifier, I know it's dumb but the professor mandated it, it's the same value as FacID from the main Faculty table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Tload( FacSSN IN NUMBER, OffYear IN NUMBE R)
    RETURN NUMBER IS Total_Course_Load NUMBER;
BEGIN 

    SELECT
        COUNT(*) INTO Total_Course_Load
    FROM
        OFFERING; 

    RETURN Total_Course_Load;

End; 

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( Get_Tload( 9002, 2017 ) );
END;
```

Comment: A database using US Social-Security-Numbers as Primary Keys for people? No, no, no, *no*, **NO!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my current code is just returning a count of every record in the table and I'm not sure why.

Your `SELECT` expression doesn't perform any filtering or grouping. I'm curious why you'd think your function would magically filter without adding a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) INTO Total_Course_Load
FROM
    OFFERING
WHERE
    OFFERINGA.FacSSN = FacSSN
    AND
    OFFERING.OffYear = OffYear;
```